# Unable to update progress bar inside a Fragment using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm unable to update the progress bar , which is in a ListView inside a Fragment. I could see the updated progress bar if I refresh the fragment! but then, as soon as the progress bar shows, the app crashes! 
In Short: I'm unable to get the list view instance in the Listener. Kindly help me out!